# Ohm's law and its relation to complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, mathematical-physics

I'm reading a piece about Ohm's law and its relation to complex numbers.  There is a piece of text about an inverse relationship, which I don't understand because it's about a capacitor. Can someone help me? **I would personally conclude that the relationship is directly proportional rather than inversely proportional.**

The text:

*Ohm's law*

Ohm's law relates the current i through a resistor R and the voltage u across the resistor R:u = i.R

*Ohm's law for sinusoidal currents:*

The above also applies to sinusoidal currents:

Suppose current () = .  (2. π. f.  + ) with t the time:
• I is the amplitude
• f is the frequency
• φ is the phase shift

Again, we can represent the current as a revolving vector.

The imaginary value (projection on the imaginary axis) gives the sinusoidal current. We use the “bold” I to indicate that it is a complex number.

The voltage then becomes: u(t) = .  (2. π. f.  + ).   = .  .  (2. π. f.  + )

• We see that the frequency and phase are preserved.

• The amplitude changes and becomes the amplitude of the current times R.

The voltage is again a spinning vector with the same frequency and phase, but the magnitude has changed. After all, we know that multiplying by a real number only changes the magnitude.

*Voltage when the resistor passes through a capacitor*

What will the voltage be if we pass the resistor through a capacitor?

Capacity:

There is a relationship between the charge q on the capacitor and the voltage u across the capacitor. This relation is the capacitance C of the capacitor:
 =  /

The voltage across the capacitor cannot suddenly change.  For the voltage to change, the charge on the capacitor must also change.  This charge is provided by the current flowing to it, thereby building up the charge.  So the voltage will only change later than the current.  The phase of the voltage will have a negative phase with respect to the current.  It can be shown that the phase difference is 90°.  The voltage thus lags behind the current by 90°.

From  = q / u we get  = q / C

It applies:

• The larger the capacitor, the more charge q is required for the voltage u to change.

• The charge q is proportional to the current i ( ~ ).  The greater the current, the more charge flows to the capacitor.

**So the voltage u will be inversely proportional to the current i. This inverse proportionality is easy to express:
 ~  / C**

*Calculation with complex numbers:*

We have yet to obtain the phase difference of 90°.  This is not possible with real numbers, but it can be done with complex numbers.  For this we introduce the notion of “pure imaginary number”.  Purely imaginary numbers are imaginary numbers whose real part is 0.

We know that multiplying a complex number by a pure positive imaginary number shifts the phase by +90°.  If we divide by a purely positive imaginary number, the phase will rotate by -90°.  We must have this.

We then obtain the expression:
= / (.)

This is equivalent to u = i.R , but R is replaced by 1/ (j.C) This is called the impedance Z of the capacitor.  Z is a complex number.

So for sinusoidal voltages holds: U = I ∙ Z

***Why is the bold text true?***

Comment: Your question is unclear to me but it regardless seems more well-suited to the physics stack exchange

Comment: Sure that "i" the the imaginary unit here. I would rather guess it is the amperage.

Comment: Does your textbook tell you which kind of circuit this discussion applies to?

Comment: The text is of alternating current...draw the phaser diagram or use kirchoff law in a simple RC circuit...you will yourself see that the current leads the voltage

Comment: Just asking, is this text referring to a sine wave current?

Comment: If it's a simple capacitor circuit then I guess it should be directly proportional (providing I am interpreting the question correctly)

Comment: You can see the above by kVL

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Yes it is! Ohm's law relates the current i through a resistor R and the voltage u across the resistor R:
 u = i.R Ohm's law for sinusoidal currents:
 The above also applies to sinusoidal currents: Suppose current () = .  (2. π. f.  + ) with t the time:
 • I is the amplitude
 • f is the frequency
 • φ is the phase shift

Comment: Where are you getting complex numbers here? The use of $i$ for amperage is unfortunate, but it has nothing to do with the imaginary number.

Comment: @WinstonCherf yeah...there are exceptions tho...like if we keep the power of a source constant then the current is inversely proportional to the voltage

Comment: You should have asked it on PSE tho

Comment: Since $q = Cu$ you have $i = \dot{q} = C \dot{u}$. I have no idea where you get  "charge q is proportional to the current" from.

Comment: Complex numbers are often used to help represent phase shifts in sinusoidal signals. What you've written here doesn't seem to get quite that far in relating Ohm's law to complex numbers. (It's hard to tell which parts of the question are your own words and which are quoting the source that you're questioning; it would help if you could indicate which is which, either with indentation or quotation marks.)

Comment: In the sentence, "So the voltage u will be inversely proportional to the current i," what exactly is being measured is unclear, since the voltage and current **at an arbitrary instant in time** are not in any fixed proportion, direct or inverse. If the sentence refers to the magnitudes of two sinusoidal signals measured across a single capacitor, then I agree the proportionality is direct and not inverse. But it's hard to tell whether that's what you're asking.

Comment: There are no complex numbers in the question, so the title is very misleading. You can take the Fourier/Laplace transform of the various quantities (assuming they exist) in which case you are now dealing with complex quantities. But the question above is strictly in the time domain.

Comment: If you could link to the piece you're reading (if it's on line), it might be interesting background to this question.

Comment: I’ve edited the text @DavidK

Comment: It looks like the bold text near the middle of the question is false for exactly the reason you propose in your first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

> So the voltage u will be inversely proportional to the current i. This inverse proportionality is easy to express:  ~  / C

The relationship between $u$ and $i$ expressed in $u \sim i/C$, where $i$ is a variable rather than the imaginary unit, says that $u$ and $i$ are directly proportional, not inversely proportional.

You are right. The statement in your source text is wrong.

Comment: The author of the source text seems to have a loose grasp on how all of this works mathematically, or at least on the language for describing the mathematics, so it may not be surprising that they state the wrong type of proportionality.